# ASP.NET MVC model binding and default constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

How do bind my domain object Car to View?

MVC says "your class must have default constructor". But I don't want to change any business rules by creating a default constructor. The only solution I can see - is to use CarView in my View and then map it to Car.

P.S. [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) wants a default constructor too, but it can be protected. This I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, its a good idea to seperate the objects that go to your view from you domain objects. This has a long list of advantages (which I am not going into now).

You can then use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map your view models to your domain objects

Comment: I agree - your UI should work with view models, not your business objects. MVC is all about separation of concerns. This may seem like a lot of additional work, but with Automapper it's peanuts and will save you  grief later on.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the object yourself and call UpdateModel to do the binding instead:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   var car = new MyCar(somethingToPassIntoTheConstructor);

   UpdateModel(car);

   // Do stuff with car.
}
```